# Is there any online Huffman code/decoder?

Tags: algorithms, compression

I need to see and work with Huffman code and see how does it compress data.

Anyone has any link of online Huffman coder and decoder (compressor)?

Comment: Look at [Huffman_coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

Comment: Did you try google search? http://planetcalc.com/2481/, http://www.cryptool-online.org/index.php?option=com_cto&view=tool&Itemid=142&lang=en

Comment: https://github.com/wilkerlucio/huffman_js

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes I did google search and I got these results, but why the lenght of what Huffman returns is more than string? I thought it will compress

Comment: Huffman tree generating: http://huffman.ooz.ie/ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HuffmanCoding.html https://errproof.com/huffman/